# Dimensions of data stored in HDF5

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have several `.h5` files which contain Pandas DataFrames created with the `.to_hdf` method. My question is quite simple : is it possible to retrieve the dimension of the DataFrame stored in the `.h5` file without loading all the data in RAM ?

Motivation : the DataFrames stored in those HDF5 files are quite big (up to several Gb) and loading all the data just to get the shape of the data is really time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably going to want to use PyTables directly.

The API reference is [here](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref.html), but basically:

```
from tables import *
h5file = open_file("yourfile.h5", mode="r")
print h5file.root.<yourdataframe>.table.shape
print len(h5file.root.<yourdataframe>.table.cols) - 1 # first col is an index
```

Also, just for clarity, HDF5 does not read all the data when a dataset is opened. That would be a peculiarity of Pandas.